# Fixing Index Out Of Bounds Exception

Tags: java, arrays, exception, indexing

I have a problem with array indexing. The code is supposed to move objects of type Ant around a 20x20 grid.

```
public class Test {
    Organism[][] grid = new Organism[20][20];

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++){
                if(grid[i][j] instanceof Ant){
                        int xpos = i;
                        int ypos = j;
                        grid[i][j].move(xpos, ypos);
                        grid[i][j].breed(xpos, ypos);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Class Ant extends Organism, class Organism extends Test.

```
public class Ant extends Organism{
    public void move(int xpos, int ypos){
    Random rand = new Random();
        int direction = rand.nextInt(3);
        if(direction == 0){
            if(grid[xpos][ypos + 1] == null && xpos <20 && ypos <20)
            {
                grid[xpos][ypos] = grid[xpos][ypos];
                grid[xpos][ypos] = null;
            {
        }
    }
}
```

The method move is supposed to choose a random direction on the grid and move the Ant there if the adjoining space is empty. It also cannot go outside the 20x20 grid. (There are three more if loops for the other directions).

If I change the sixth line in the move method to:

```
if(grid[xpos][ypos] == null && xpos <20 && ypos <20)
```

Then no error is thrown.

I hesitate to post this because its probably a small error on my part but I have been staring at this for several hours.

Assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operands for an `&&` are evaluated from left to right, and the evaluation stops if one of them evaluates to `false`. So if one or more of the operands are potentially dangerous (such as an array lookup that might go out of bounds), and some of the other operands are supposed to protect against this, the protection operands need to go first. Also, you need to check the indices you're actually using, namely `xpos` and `ypos + 1`, and you forgot to use `ypos + 1` in the assignment that moves the ant:

```
if (xpos < 20 && ypos + 1 < 20 && grid[xpos][ypos + 1] == null) {
    grid[xpos][ypos + 1] = grid[xpos][ypos];
    grid[xpos][ypos] = null;
}
```

(And, assuming that `xpos` and `ypos` are valid indices, you don't need to check `xpos`.)

Comment: Did you make a similar change to the other `if`s? At what line is the exception thrown, and what is the message?

Comment: By the way, it will definitely crash in `main()` because you first move the ant out of its original cell, and then try to make the same cell (which is now empty) breed.

Comment: Now I understand. I have to check that the new index will not be out of bounds.  It compiles now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Splendid! (Technically, you have to check all indices you're using - both the ones you're moving from and the ones you're moving to - but given the way your code is structured, you can rely upon `xpos` and `ypos` themselves always being within range.)

Comment: I don't want to keep bothering you but the Ants are not moving. The code I'm using to draw the Ants is too long to put in a comment but I make a new 2d array of type char and iterate through the grid array and replace ant objects with 'O's then printing that array. None of the arts are moving though

Comment: I can't figure that one out without seeing the code, so please post a new question about it (and feel free to post a link to it in a comment here). If there is too much code, please try to simplify the code and remove less relevant parts of it (e.g., if you display the ants in a GUI, try to show the ants as characters in the console instead) - maybe this process will even let you discover the bug yourself.